# Can a component get the attributes that are in the html tag

Tags: angular

So for instance I have my component that has some css classes that have been added by another component

```
<component-a class="valid" ></component-a>
```

Can I get hold of these classes in the class declaration

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'component-a',
  template: ''
})
export class componentA { }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities.

First you use a parameter binding like that:

```
<component-a [class]="'valid'" ></component-a>
```

That means you can access the 'class' with an Input variable

```
@Input() class: string;
```

If you want to use a class attribute like in your question then you can access the attribute by a code like that:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

  ngOnInit(){
    // get the list of classnames
    this.classList = this.el.nativeElement.classList;
    console.log(this.classList);
  }
```

[Plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/pljRObuxENRUNSNSuvcY/)

Comment: In your first option I think you may need to use `@Input('class') classAttribute: string;` to avoid trying to use a reserved word as a property name.